# Speciale price Magento

Tags: magento, price

I have set a speciale price for a product in the backend but when I go to the product page the price appears and then off again. Also in the cart it's not display.

See link what I mean : [Link](http://www.bambinotino.nl/bambinotino-broek-in-de-kleur-lime-groen)

Comment: Are you able to view **/app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/YOUR_PACKAGE/catalog/product/view.phtml**. If so, can you post the price section up? You may not be using the final price in the theme.

Comment: Meaby you can see what is not good ? http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3941

Comment: Hazel Abdullah could you please look for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your code, find this on line 177:

```
<?php echo $priceProperties; ?>
```

And replace with this :

```
echo Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->calcProductPriceRule($_product,$_product->getPrice());
```

I believe your theme doesn't take into account the discount. This would be a bug with the theme development.

This is untested (as I don't have full access to your theme) code so let me know if you have any trouble.